# could not access file wal2json no such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, change-data-capture

I am new to PostgreSQL. I am trying to implement logical replication in PostgreSQL installed in my laptop.

When I run the following query to create a replication slot, I am getting

```
could not access file wal2json: no such file or directory
```

```
SELECT * FROM pg_create_logical_replication_slot('test_slot', 'wal2json');
```

After a search in google, I understand that wal2json is an additional extension kind of thing which needs to be setup separately.

Does anyone have an idea how to setup "wal2json" in PostgreSQL installed on a local laptop (Windows OS)?

Answer (score 1):

[wal2json](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) is a plugin (not an extension) that needs to be installed separately. The README.md file has some info about installing it for Windows. I think that you will have an easier time installing and managing PostgreSQL and the plugin inside a Linux virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I have seen this github link but it is not clear on how to install in windows. when I follow the steps to create dll using microsoft visual studio. it is giving some compilation error. Hence, I am checking if there is any other option.

Comment: Then maybe ask a question about that compilation error.

Comment: As @LaurenzAlbe wrote: ask about your real obstacle. You can also open an issue in the Github repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the binaries for wal2json here: https://www.striim.com/docs/smsgc/en/smsgc-how-to-guides/postgresql-to-google-cloud-postgresql-migration-guide/set-up-the-postgresql-source.html

(They're provided by a third-party, Striim, but the company appears legit, so I'm not concerned by it.)

After downloading, copy the dll file into the `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\VERSION\lib` folder, and restart PostgreSQL.

**EDIT**: Actually, on attempting to use the wal2json extension from NodeJS, it appears something is incompatible between the prebuilt Windows 10 binary above, and my Postgres install. I get the following error in Postgraphile:

```
Could not Initiate PgLDSSourcePlugin, continuing without LDS live queries. Error: Couldn't create replication slot, seems you don't have wal2json installed? Error: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/lib/wal2json.dll": The specified procedure could not be found.
```

So in the end I had to compile the dll myself, as the [wal2json readme](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json#windows) specifies. (I was getting a compilation error, so I tried upgrading Visual Studio from 2015 to 2019. Once I did so, the build completed easily however. I just opened the `wal2json.vcxproj` file, pressed `Build->Build wal2json`, then copied the dll file it produced into the PostgreSQL `lib` folder.)

Comment: Unfortunately, at the time I write this comment, the link https://www.striim.com/docs/smsgc/en/smsgc-how-to-guides/postgresql-to-google-cloud-postgresql-migration-guide/set-up-the-postgresql-source.html is not found (http status 404).